# Got trouble with loading different images in each row of a listView via a custom adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, listadapter

i used this [tutorial](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/)   to learn how to set up my own adapter and filling a listView with custom rows.

Now im trying to get a different image (image1, image2, etc.) in each row using the adapter.
Can anyone provide me a hint, where i have to implement the fetching of the images!?

snippets from main.java:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
    m_orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
    int r = 0;
    this.m_adapter = new OrderAdapter(this, R.layout.row, m_orders);
    setListAdapter(this.m_adapter);
    viewOrders = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getOrders();
        }
    };
    Thread thread =  new Thread(null, viewOrders, "MagentoBackground");
    thread.start();     
    private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(m_orders != null && m_orders.size() > 0){
            m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            for(int i=0;i<m_orders.size();i++)
            m_adapter.add(m_orders.get(i));
        }
        m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
        m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
private void getOrders(){
      try{
          m_orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
          Order o1 = new Order();
          o1.setOrderName("SF services");
          Order o2 = new Order();
          o2.setOrderName("SF Advertisement");
          m_orders.add(o1);
          m_orders.add(o2);
          Thread.sleep(2000);
          Log.i("ARRAY", ""+ m_orders.size());
        } catch (Exception e) { 
          Log.e("BACKGROUND_PROC", e.getMessage());
        }
        runOnUiThread(returnRes);
    }


private class OrderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Order> {

    private ArrayList<Order> items;

    public OrderAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Order> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            }
            Order o = items.get(position);
            if (o != null) {
                    TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
                    if (tt != null) {
                          tt.setText("Name: "+o.getOrderName());                            }
            }
            return v;
    }
```

and row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip" />  
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toptext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

thx in advance. i think its not too hard to find the answer. but im a rookie and got lost a bit :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are asking about Loading images over the network.

```
Get them in 

     @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           ...
        }
```

using Lazy loading of images for more information of lazy loading...just google it ...

Comment: the lazy-list looks pretty neat, but that one step ahead of what i want to achieve. i'm just trying to teach my adapter how to draw different .png from the resource-folder. It is inside the getView, but the LayoutInflater confuses me so far :/

Comment: Hi try this tutorial...If you unable understand it...don't mind to ask me..I'll be there for you....http://www.javasrilankansupport.com/2012/05/android-listview-example-with-image-and.html

Comment: thanks for your help! my company's android-developer will be back tomorrow, so i can ask him how to optimize my code. its running by now, but i dont think it is like it should/is meant to be ;)